# How to find all possible sequences of elements in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list [2,3,4]. How do I find all possible sequence of elements in the list?
So the output should be:
[2,3,4]
[2,4,3]
[3,2,4]
[3,4,2]
[4,2,3]
[4,3,2]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this easily using [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations([2, 3, 4]))
[(2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 4), (3, 4, 2), (4, 2, 3), (4, 3, 2)]
```

And if for some reason you need lists instead of tuples:

```
>>> map(list, permutations([2, 3, 4]))
[[2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 3], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: Maybe add a link to http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for permutations, something like this should work:

```
import itertools
itertools.permutations([2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 2):

a start of a great lottery program except data would be formated as such

```
ist(permutations([2, 3, 4],[7,2,5],[8,1,4,9]))
```

the problem is that the first group is used to create numbers in first column only
the secound is for 2 column and 3rd is for 3rd

the output will be a set of 3 numbers just that the permutation is different

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know:

```
def unique_perms(elems):
    """returns non-duplicate permutations 
       if duplicate elements exist in `elems`
    """
    from itertools import permutations
    return list(set(permutations(elems)))
```

But if you're doing something like this:

```
print len(unique_perms(elems))
```

Then try this:

```
def fac(n):
    """n!"""
    if n == 1: return n
    return n * fac(n -1)

def unique_perm_count(elems)
    n = len(elems)
    return fac(2 * n) / fac(n) ** 2
```